# Cross domain call not working in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui

I am making a asynchronous request to different server for some data using jquery. It works fine in IE, but doesn't work in FireFox and Chrome, when it reaches the code where the request to other server is made, it freezes there and a blank page is shown. If I remove that piece of code, the ajax works fine.

Also, when I place a breakpoint at document.ready, the breakpoint is hit when debugging using IE, but it's not hit when debugging using FireFox.

Following is the JQuery I am using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.tabs a, .tabs span').livequery('click', function () {

        var currentTab = $(this).parents('li:first');

        if (!currentTab.is('.active')) {
            var currentContent = $('.tab_container .' + currentTab.attr('class'));

            $('.tabs li').removeClass("active");
            currentTab.addClass("active");
            var url = $(this).attr("href");

            var newContent = "";
            if (currentContent.length == 0) {
                $.get(url, {}, function (result) {
                    $('#tabs.tab_container div:visible').fadeOut(100, function () {
                        $('#tabs.tab_container')
                        .html(result)
                        .fadeIn(100);
                    });

                }, 'html');
            }
            else {
                $('#tabs.tab_container div:visible').fadeOut(100, function () {
                    currentContent.fadeIn(100);
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for [jQuery.Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

If you're after JSON responses, then you should consider using the JSONP option that has been rolled into the [GetJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

There are a couple of people out there who have however provided some workarounds for the Get limitation:

- [The jQuery Cross Domain Ajax Guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)
- [Cross Domain Requests with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)